# Argument passing failing

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have this code:

```
 def begin(): # the main attraction.
    print("Select difficulty level\n")
    print("E - Easy. Data set is 5 numbers long, and the set is sorted\n")
    print("M - Medium. Data set is 7 numbers long and the set is sorted\n")
    print("H - Hard. Data set is 10 numbers long and the set is not sorted\n")
    difficultySelect = input()
    if difficultySelect == "E" or "e":
        worksheet.beginGameLoop("easy")
    elif difficultySelect == "M" or "m":
        worksheet.beginGameLoop("med")
    elif difficultySelect == "H" or "h":
        worksheet.beginGameLoop("hard")
def beginGameLoop(gameDifficulty):
    if gameDifficulty == "easy":
        length = 5
        sorting = True
    elif gameDifficulty == "med":
        length = 7
        sorting = True
    elif gameDifficulty == "hard":
       length = 10
       sorting = False
       for questions in range(10):
           invalidPrinted = False
           questions, answer, qType = worksheet.createQuestion(length, sorting)
```

When I run it, it appears to be stuck on the variables from easy-mode. What could be the issue?
EDIT: the whole thing is [here.](http://pastebin.com/W04NWT3F)

Comment: Most likely the gameDifficulty variable you are testing is actually "easy". What's the rest of your code?

Comment: is that for loop supposed to be nested there? How come you don't have one for the other difficulties? you could you use 'for questions in range(length): etc etc.

Comment: @Boo can you reread the code? I left out some probably important things.

Comment: Also @Totem, can you reread the code? I left some important parts. I apparently can't add more than one user at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if difficultySelect == "E" or "e":
    worksheet.beginGameLoop("easy")
elif difficultySelect == "M" or "m":
    worksheet.beginGameLoop("med")
elif difficultySelect == "H" or "h":
```

it should be:

```
if difficultySelect == "E" or difficultySelect == "e":
    worksheet.beginGameLoop("easy")
elif difficultySelect == "M" or difficultySelect == "m":
    worksheet.beginGameLoop("med")
elif difficultySelect == "H" or difficultySelect == "h":
```

or even better:

```
if difficultySelect in ("E", "e"):
    worksheet.beginGameLoop("easy")
elif difficultySelect in ("M", "m"):
    worksheet.beginGameLoop("med")
elif difficultySelect in ("H", "h"):
```

The statement `if x == 'a' or 'b'` will always be true. In Python the result of the `or` statement is `False` or the value of the first evaluated statement that wasn't `False`. So in your case it will be either `True` if `difficultySelect` was equal to `E` for example, or `e`. And `e` is always not `False` - that's why always the first condition was fulfilled.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. This reminds of the time when I struggled for an hour before realizing int() doesn't work in place.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `for` loop is indented too far.

```
if gameDifficulty == "easy":
    length = 5
    sorting = True
elif gameDifficulty == "med":
    length = 7
    sorting = True
elif gameDifficulty == "hard":
    length = 10
    sorting = False

for questions in range(length):
    invalidPrinted = False
    questions, answer, qType = worksheet.createQuestion(length, sorting)
```

Comment: Actually, it isn't. My bad, I forgot to include the def statement I was using.

Comment: @user2797412 are you sure? as written, the `for` loop will only work when `gameDifficulty == "hard"`

Comment: The loop does work, it just uses all the variables from the easy section.

Comment: @user2797412 the indentation in your pastebin link is different that in your question.